# Доступ к postgresql через openvpn

Tags: postgresql, сеть, openvpn

Имеется удаленный сервер под ubuntu 18 с настроенным openvpn (порты 1194,100,101,443; подсети 10.8.0.0/24,10.8.1.0/24,10.8.2.0/24,10.8.3.0/24) и postgresql 10. Не могу достучаться до postgres из сети openvpn. При этом доступ извне открывается нормально. К примеру samba доступна из openvpn сетей, т.е. проблем с роутингом в принципе нет.

В конфигах постгреса включен доступ:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
host all all all trust
```

Фаервол настроен:

```
Status: active
     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 1194                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] 100                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 4] 101                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 5] 443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 6] 445/tcp                    ALLOW IN    10.8.0.0/24
[ 7] 445/tcp                    ALLOW IN    10.8.1.0/24
[ 8] 445/tcp                    ALLOW IN    10.8.2.0/24
[ 9] 445/tcp                    ALLOW IN    10.8.3.0/24
[10] 5432/tcp                   ALLOW IN    10.8.2.0/24
[11] 5432/tcp                   ALLOW IN    10.8.1.0/24
[12] 5432/tcp                   ALLOW IN    10.8.3.0/24
[13] 5432/tcp                   ALLOW IN    10.8.0.0/24
[14] 1194 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[15] 22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[16] 100 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[17] 101 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[18] 443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Сервис запущен:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1246/smbd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      785/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1079/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8529/postgres
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1040/openvpn
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1246/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      1246/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1079/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      8529/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      1246/smbd
```

Скан портов:

```
Nmap scan report for 10.8.2.1
Host is up (0.064s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
100/tcp closed newacct
443/tcp open   https
445/tcp open   microsoft-ds
```

Ради эксперимента открывал доступ к серверу извне:

```
ufw allow from any to any port 5432 proto tcp
```

После этого он доступен через интернет

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
100/tcp  closed newacct
443/tcp  open   https
5432/tcp closed postgresql
```

но продолжает быть недоступным из сетей 10.8.0.0/24,10.8.1.0/24,10.8.2.0/24,10.8.3.0/24.

Чего еще не хватает этому паразиту?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что партизан заземлился и дальше localhost ничего не слышит. А если серьезно, глянте в настройках пг какой интерфейс он слушает

Comment: Стоит listen_addresses = '*', но я ставил и "localhost, 10.8.2.1" - бесполезно. Тем более тогда бы он явно не был доступен через интернет.

Comment: глянте [вот эту](https://vivazzi.pro/it/remote-access-postgresql/) статью. Если поможет оформите как ответ, мне просто не на чем сейчас тестить. (соответственно с поправкой на версию)

Comment: У меня сделано все что указано в данной статье. Проблема явно в другом и связана с особенностями доступа через подсеть openvpn.

Comment: Кстати фаервол тут не причем, я его вообще отключал. Из интернета постгрес естественно становится доступен, а через vpn - нет.

Comment: Если честно, то я в свое время решил подобную проблему с помощью `ssh -NfL 5432:localhost:5432 remote_user@remote_host` и коннектился к пострегрес на локальной машине через localhost

Comment: конфигов openvpn'а сервера/клиентов для полноты картины не хватает... ЗЫ: огнестену пробовал дропнуть?

Comment: Вот я дятел то. У меня роутером отсекались порты выше 1024 вне vpn, чтобы туда торренты не лезли. И постгрес с ними :) Все заработало! Надо бы вопрос как-то закрыть ибо он получается некорректный по сути.